# Python - Finding Twitter Handles

Tags: python, text

I am new to Python, but trying to pull out all Twitter Handles from a list of bios. Basically I need to pull out what comes after the '@'.

Example Input: ['Hello @handle1', '@handle2 @handle3 hello', 'words3', '@handle4']

Output: ['handle1', 'handle2', 'handle3', 'handle4']

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you should post what you have already tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are your friend.

```py
import re
import itertools

bios = ['Hello @handle1', '@handle2 @handle3 hello', 'words3', '@handle4']
handles = itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall(r"@(\w+)", bio) for bio in bios)
```

There's a lot going on here, so let's unwrap this a bit:

```py
all_handles = []
for bio in bios:
    # bio = 'Hello @handle1', or '@handle2 @handle3 hello'
    this_bio_handles = re.findall(r"""
@                      # a literal "@" sign
(                      # beginning of capture group
    \w+                # one or more "Word" characters (a-z, 0-9, and space)
)                      # end of capture group""", bio, flags=re.X)
    # this_bio_handles = ['handle1'], or ['handle2', 'handle3']
    all_handles.append(this_bio_handles)

# all_handles = [['handle1'], ['handle2', 'handle3'], ['handle4']]
handles = itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_handles)
# itertools.chain produces an iterator from an iterable.
# itertools.chain.from_iterable produces an iterator from an iterable of iterables
# so handles ends up looking like 'handle1' 'handle2' 'handle3' 'handle4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex or importing modules:

```py
text = ['Hello @handle1', '@handle2 @handle3 hello', 'words3', '@handle4']

handles = [word[1:] for word_group in text for word in word_group.split() if word.startswith('@')]
```